# Not able to update a record in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am writing an API using mongo express and node and I have two collections as of now 1) users 2) userlist

I am trying to implement change password functionality for the user and want to update the password for the login user.This is my code for the api.

Facing cast to string failed for value error.

```
    const express = require("express");
const app  = express();
const bodyParser  =  require('body-parser');
const port = 4000;
const jwt =  require('jsonwebtoken');  //used to create, sign , and verify tokens
const logger = require('morgan');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/saddleHorseacademy");

//Setting up basic middleware for all express requests
app.use(logger('dev')); //Log requests to API using morgan

//Enabling CORS from the client side
app.use(function (request,response,next) {
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','PUT ,GET ,POST ,DELETE ,OPTIONS');
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials");
    response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
    next();
});

var registerSchema  =  new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    address: String,
    birthDay: Date,
    packageOption: String,
    batchOption: String,
    startDate: Date,
    endDate: Date,
    phoneNumber: Number,
    emailValue: String,
    specialRemarks: String
});

// var changePassword = new mongoose.Schema({
//     username : String,
//     newPassword : String,
// });

var createUser = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName : String,
  password : String
});

var students = mongoose.model("students",registerSchema);

var userList = mongoose.model("UserList",createUser);

// var passwordChange = mongoose.model("UserList",changePassword);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", (request,response) =>
{
  response.send("hello");
});

// post call for creating user
app.post("/addStudent",(request,response)=>{
  var myData = new students(request.body);

  myData.save().then(item=>{
      response.send('Student successfully registerd');
  })
  .catch(error =>{
    response.status(400).send('Student not successfully registered');
  });
});

//updating the password
app.put("/loginPassword",(request,response)=>{
      var newPassword =  new userList(request.body);
      var query = {userName:request.body.userName};

      userList.findOneAndUpdate(query,{$set:{password:newPassword}},{new:false},function(error,doc) {
        if(error)
        {
          console.log(error);
          response.send("Password not updated");
        }
        else {
          response.send("password updated");
        }
      })

});
// post call creating user
app.post("/loginPassword",(request,response)=>{
    var myUsers = new userList(request.body);

    myUsers.save().then(item2=>{
      response.send("User Created");
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      response.status(400).send("not able to create user");
    });
});

app.listen(port,()=>{
  console.log("server listening to port" +port);
})
```

so what I want is in my create user schema my password should get updated when I call app.put api from the front-end. Please can some-one help by writing the exact query.

When i tried to do findOneandUpdate() then i got cast ti string error. please can any body help . or write the put request. thank's

Answer (score 0):

You created a variable `newPassword`  which is a `model` object, you are passing it as a `string`.

Change your `query` object to:

```
    {$set: {password: request.body.newPassword}}
```